# How to handle list of list in scala and add elements itertively

Tags: java, scala, geometry, scala-collections

I'm pretty new to scala, any help will be appreciated

Lets say, for example, I compute points [Lat, long] in a for loop, how to add them in a mutable list iteratively

eg:

```
var points = MutableList(List(Double,Double))

for( i <- 0 to 100 ){
var (lat,long) = customfunction() // lat and long returned are in double datatype
points+=List(lat,lon)

}
```

**error faced**:
command-3921379637506779:74: error: type mismatch;
 found   : lat.type (with underlying type Double)
 required: Nothing
      points+=List(lat,lon)
                   ^
command-3921379637506779:74: error: type mismatch;
 found   : lon.type (with underlying type Double)
 required: Nothing
      points+=List(lat,lon)

Am I in the right direction in using the mutable list or any other best approach available, pls let me know

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to determine what you're actually trying to accomplish. Does `customfunction()` return a tuple, `(Double,Double)`, or a list, `List[Double]`?

Whatever it returns, if you want a `List` of 100 such elements, then try this.

```
val points = List.fill(100)(customfunction())
```

As a general rule, avoid mutation. No `var`s and few, if any, mutable collections.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
var points = new mutable.MutableList[List[Double]]

  for (i <- 0 to 5) {
    var (lat, long) = customfunction() // lat and long returned are in double datatype
    points += List(lat, long)
  }

 println(points)

  def customfunction(): (Double, Double) = {
    return (1.0, 1.0)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to use case classes as shown below:

```
case class LatLong(lat: Double, long: Double)

var points: MutableList[LatLong] = MutableList()

def customfunction(): LatLong = {
    LatLong(1.0, 1.0)
}

for (i <- 0 to 5) {
    var currLatLong = customfunction() // lat and long returned are in double datatype
    points += currLatLong
 }

println(points)
```

**A Functional Approach**

```
case class LatLong(lat: Double, long: Double)

def customfunction(): LatLong = {
    LatLong(1.0, 1.0)
}

// No mutable points list is required.
val points = (0 to 5).map(e => customfunction()).toList

println(points)

// Output
//List(LatLong(1.0,1.0), LatLong(1.0,1.0), LatLong(1.0,1.0), LatLong(1.0,1.0), LatLong(1.0,1.0), LatLong(1.0,1.0))
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val points = new ListBuffer[List[(Double, Double)]]()

for( i <- 0 to 100 ) {
  var result: (Double, Double) = customfunction()
  points += List(result)
}
```